# Position absolute and relative IE7 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have two divs. First has `position:absolute` and another one has `position:relative`.

```
   <div class="first-div">
    abc
   </div>

   <div class="second-div">
   xyz
   </div>
```

The problem is in IE7 when hover the first div, the first div is under the second div. In CSS `z-index:100`; for first div and `z-index:0;` for the second div but it does not work. Any help to solve this issue?

For other browsers it's working well, only in IE7 is this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a z-index bug in IE 7. Setting the parent z-index to a higher value can fix the problem.

```
<div class="parent" style="position: relative; z-index:200;">
  <div class="first" style="position: absolute; z-index:100;"></div>

</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Something like that I suppose - without seeing some of your code it's hard to tell.

Comment: I hadn't set for begining a z-index for parent of first div and when I set a z-index bigger then second div the problem is resolved

Comment: @BoiculeseIuli, it should be noted that versions of Internet Explorer treats the absolute elements and the relative elements and two different sets of objects; effectively giving you two unique sets of z-index's.